# Can I move my Applications folder to my external SSD or will Mac OS X Yosemite complain about it?

Tags: macos, ssd

I want to move Applications folder to my external SSD but I do not know if Mac OS X likes that.

Comment: Will it be faster if I install my operating system on the external SSD with USB 3.0? I want the best performance with an external SSD.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing it is the following:

- Move the content of your `Applications` folder, leaving the folder untouched.
- Symlink every file in your new folder.

And example, let's you want to move the `Calendar.app`:

```
mv /Applications/Calendar.app /yourssd/Applications
ln -s /yourssd/Applications /Applications/Calendar.app
```

Then you will be able to execute calendar as usual.

Comment: Why not just symlink the Applications folder?

Comment: If I remember well, I believe that you won't be able to move all apps.